# Treeview Clone event

Tags: c#, treeview, clone

What I would like the following code to do is add a node and its directory structure from one tree to another when clicked, but the line of code is incorrect, and I'm not sure what I can do to fix it...
What is the correct way to use node.Clone() in this situation?

I'm sure its a simple fix.

```
private void treeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    tVS.Nodes.Add(e.Node.Clone());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the line of code is incorrect"?

Comment: tVS.Nodes.Add(e.Node.Clone()); has an error. I assume it is a syntax error, but i just want it to copy the structure of one node into the other tree and add it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast is required here

```
tVS.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)e.Node.Clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Node newNode = (Node)e.Node.Clone();
tVS.Nodes.Add(newNode);
```

Comment: Actually, as `is` not correct cast here, as `object` MUST be a node

Comment: Thats close, but i realized i need a cast.

Comment: @Mac "(obj)obj" can throw ex but "obj as obj" return null if faild. But both is "cast"

Comment: @jrb It would not allow me to use "as Node" in my code, and tell me there was an error, but the cast works fine

Comment: ok maybe it had to be a Treenode, just explaining the "as" syntax